# Выполнить метод из стороннего класса

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Столкнулась с такой проблемой: Принимаю callback с сайта и обрабатываю его

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly CallbackObjectForJs _callBackObjectForJs;
    private readonly CallbackObjectSaveSettings _callbackObjectSaveSettings;
    private static XmlHelper _xmlhelper;

    public  MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _xmlhelper = new XmlHelper();
        var hostInterface = new HostInterface(this);
        Browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("hostInterface", hostInterface);
        Browser.ConsoleMessage += (s, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"BROWSERCONSOLE: {e.Source}:{e.Line} - {e.Message}");
        };

        _callBackObjectForJs = new CallbackObjectForJs();
        _callbackObjectSaveSettings = new CallbackObjectSaveSettings();

        Browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", _callBackObjectForJs);
        Browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", _callbackObjectSaveSettings);
    }

    public class CallbackObjectForJs
    {
        public void showMessage(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg);

        }
    }

    public class CallbackObjectSaveSettings
    {
        public void showMessage(string msg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }

        public void getAuthUser(string login, string password)
        {
            _xmlhelper.UpdateSettingValue("user_login", login);
            _xmlhelper.UpdateSettingValue("user_password", UserDataProtected.Shifrovka(password, "wsprod"));
            userBarGrid.Visibility = true;  // ОШИБКА Требуется указать ссылку на объект
        }
    }
}
```

После чего хочу запустить метод loadUserData(), но getAuthUser ругается на не статичный метод (указывала public static void loadUserData, начинает ругаться уже внутренний код). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить? Спасибо!

Comment: Как решить? Сделать статическим и исправить ошибки или как то получить ссылку на экзепляр нужного класса с этим методом и вызвать его. А вообще не понятно зачем вам это надо, что вы делать с этим собрались, может и не надо оно вам вовсе - но без кода это никак не понять

Comment: @tym32167 когда я получаю callback, то записываю полученные данные в файл, после чего мне нужно сделать видимым некоторые элементы MainWindow

Comment: Вы меня этим только больше запутали :) Исходя из тех данных, что вы привели, я не могу ничего вам посоветовать. Пожалуйста, подготовьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы было ясно где у вас проблема.

Comment: @tym32167 в общем.. :)  У меня в окне есть Grid, у которого установлено свойство Hidden, все, что мне надо, это после getAuthUser метода переключить свойство Grid'a на Visible, ибо в нем содержаться элементы, которые должны быть отображены только после обработки метода getAuthUser

Comment: Подробности лушче, конечно, заносить в сам вопрос. Если все, что нужно - это сделать грид видимым, то вам подойдет ```myGrid.Visible = true``` или что то типа того. При чем тут нестатические методы мне не понятно :)

Comment: @tym32167 userBarGrid.Visible подсвечивает красным. Grid MainWindow.userBarGrid требуется ссылка на объект

Comment: Ваш колбек где находится? Как вызывается? У него есть доступ к экземпляру окна вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 https://goo.gl/16GCbo  ссылка на картинку

Comment: пожалуйста, обновите всей этой информацией ваш вопрос, и ставьте туда код, но только текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: @tym32167 обновила вопрос

Comment: Спасибо. написал вам ответ. Надеюсь, помжет решить вашу пролему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не вдаваться в подробности как лучше писать код и зачем вообще такое делать, а просто сконцентрироваться на том, чтобы решить ту проблему, о которой вы спрашиваете, то вы можете решть её, пробросив экземпляр вашего окна в ваши коллбеки

```
public class MainWindow
{
    ......

    _callbackObjectSaveSettings = new CallbackObjectSaveSettings(this);
    ......
}

public class CallbackObjectSaveSettings
{
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;
    public CallbackObjectSaveSettings(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public void getAuthUser(string login, string password)
    {
        ......
        ......
        _mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> _mainWindow.userBarGrid.Visibility = true);
    }
}
```

Comment: _mainWindow.userBarGrid.Visibility = true;  - Ошибка -
 cannot convert source to bool      -   _mainWindow.userBarGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; - вот так без ошибок, только элемент по прежнему скрытый  (

Comment: А вы поставьте там брейкпоинт - этот код вообще вызывается?

Comment: Вызывается, а толку нет, далее появляется окно и все

Comment: Раз код вызывается, но грид все ещё не видимый, то покажите ваш XAML код, возможно он прояснит проблему.

Comment: <Grid x:Name="userBarGrid" Visibility="Hidden"> тут куча элементов  </Grid>

Comment: Если вы в XAML коде поменяете ```Visibility="Hidden"```  на ```Visibility="Visible"``` - у вас грид появится?

Comment: Поменяла на Visible, а в коде наоборот, грид отображается, но не пропадает... то есть толку нет вообще

Comment: @Елизавета Понял вас, я не учел, что вызов может идти из другого потока. Поменял в ответе последнюю строчку, попробуйте ещё раз

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло.